# Read more than one file

Tags: c#, pdfium

I am writing a pdf to word converter which works perfectly fine for me. But I want to be able to convert more than one file.

What happens now is that it read the first file and does the convert process.

```
public static void PdfToImage()
{
    try
    {
        Application application = null;
        application = new Application();
        var doc = application.Documents.Add();



        string path = @"C:\Users\Test\Desktop\pdfToWord\";
        foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.pdf"))
        {
            using (var document = PdfiumViewer.PdfDocument.Load(file))
            {
                int pagecount = document.PageCount;
                for (int index = 0; index < pagecount; index++)
                {
                    var image = document.Render(index, 200, 200, true);
                    image.Save(@"C:\Users\chnikos\Desktop\pdfToWord\output" + index.ToString("000") + ".png", ImageFormat.Png);
                    application.Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture(@"C:\Users\chnikos\Desktop\pdfToWord\output" + index.ToString("000") + ".png");

                }
                string getFileName = file.Substring(file.LastIndexOf("\\"));
                string getFileWithoutExtras = Regex.Replace(getFileName, @"\\", "");
                string getFileWihtoutExtension = Regex.Replace(getFileWithoutExtras, @".pdf", "");

                string fileName = @"C:\Users\Test\Desktop\pdfToWord\" + getFileWihtoutExtension;
                doc.PageSetup.PaperSize = WdPaperSize.wdPaperA4;

                foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.InlineShape inline in doc.InlineShapes)
                {

                    if (inline.Height > inline.Width)
                    {
                        inline.ScaleWidth = 250;
                        inline.ScaleHeight = 250;
                    }

                }
                doc.PageSetup.TopMargin = 28.29f;
                doc.PageSetup.LeftMargin = 28.29f;
                doc.PageSetup.RightMargin = 30.29f;
                doc.PageSetup.BottomMargin = 28.29f;

                application.ActiveDocument.SaveAs(fileName, WdSaveFormat.wdFormatDocument);
                doc.Close();
            }


        }
```

I thought that with my foreach that problem should not occur. And yes there are more than one pdf in this folder

Comment: You open the `doc` _outside_ the `foreach` loop and `doc.Close()` it after you finished the first file _inside_ the `foreach`. I guess you want to move the line `var doc = application.Documents.Add();` _inside_ the `foreach` loop, but I'm not experienced with office interaction.

Comment: @RenéVogt So I moved the doc.Close(); outside the foreach loop and now it seams to create for every pdf a word file but the "output" images are still according to the first pdf it reads and not from the others

Comment: It seems you don't want to combine all pdf files into one word file, so you need to add a new word document _foreach_ pdf document. So move the line `doc = application.Documents.Add()` _inside_ the loop instead of moving the `doc.Close()` outside.

Comment: @RenéVogt You are absolute right how stupid of me! it works totally as expected, want to post it as a answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
var doc = application.Documents.Add();
```

is **outside** the `foreach` loop. So you only create *a single* word document for all your *.pdf files.

Move the above line **inside** the `foreach` loop to add a new word document for each *.pdf file.